# Are questions about item viablility allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I recently asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173240/is-the-new-bloodthirster-viable), it was "closed as primarily opinion-based".

Why is it considered opinion-based? There are item stats and damage that the marksmen will be doing to be considered, and calculations have to be done. That is basically what I had been looking for, and it is why I asked the question. I would like to ask other questions along these lines as more items will be added, and I want professional answers from players who are more experienced than I am.

I am a league of legends player and I am trying to improve my overall knowledge of the game. Normally I would ask streamers, however I am working now and most of the streamers I used to watch are at odd times, it is difficult for me to do that as the times-zone are 8-9 hours apart.

Comment: I'm no LoL player, but this discussion would seem to be related to "[Are questions of champion viability allowed?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6788/are-questions-of-champion-viability-allowed?rq=1)". Where the prevailing answer seems to be that viability questions are allowed as long as the scope is narrowed. I feel the body of your question sufficiently narrows the focus, and for my part, have voted to re-open it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aaah yess. The POB thingy again. I think this will be a neverending discussion when related to competitive online games since everyone does something different, and yet there are the "unspoken rules" of viability.

Now to the question itself and why I think it was closed: 
[The original Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/173240/1) was a wall of text with a bad title. After the question got 3 close votes, it was edited 2 times to make it more readable/understandable. But the question still got closed. Why? Well many people don't know how far questions about "Viability" in a game like League are accurately answerable.

In competitive online games basically everything related to gameplay is subjective. So should questions about these topics be prohibited in general? I think not. An experienced League player will be able to answer [good subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) questions. **This question is a good subjective Question.** In general I think questions about Viability and Strategy are good subjective questions. Of course they will be more complex to answer but they can still be accurate. In this case of this Question you can create an answer based on the 3 Main aspects of Competitive gaming: **Calculating the stats, Watching statistics and Playing the Game**. And this Answer will be accurrate.

The question shouldn't be closed as primarily opinion based. It is answerable based on facts and the main problem with POB questions is that there can't be a single answer. This is **not** the case here. This is also **not** the case with "viability" questions in general. Strategy questions are more subjective than viability ones and those are [explicitly allowed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

Comment: -1 You continue to strawman other voters' reasons.  While you may feel it was closed in error, assigning motives that you think are invalid to actions you disagree with is not the way to do it.

Comment: @Frank I actually see the problem that it was closed as POB. And if you read the [what should I avoid asking section](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) you can see that this question fits more into the "Constructive Subjective Questions" part while it has absolutely none of the "Bad subjective" aspects (Based on Facts, Answer with clear explanation and even 1 correct answer). And I just say that it's rather hard to judge if a question is good or bad subjective for people who don't play a certain game. And could you please explain to me why this is a "Bad subjective Question"?

Comment: I'm not commenting on the question viability whatsoever.  I'm staying out of that entirely.  I'm pointing out that you have no idea why people voted the way they do, and their votes are as valid as your own.  Assigning motives to their actions to give you something to attack does not reflect well on you.  Yeah, they don't play LoL.  That doesn't mean their reasons for closing are bad in any sense.  You're going, "They don't play LoL, they don't know what they're talking about."  Perhaps they do.  Not to mention, at least one user explained to you why they voted in the manner they did in chat.

Comment: @Frank I assume they voted the way they did becasuse they thought it's a bad subjective question. Other than that there is no reason to VTC a reason as POB. And as already mentioned it's hard to figure out whether a question is good or bad subjective if you don't play the game. Of course the fact that people want to keep the site clean is a good thing, but at the same time i think closevotes shouldn't be thrown around just because something "seems" like it would be a reason to close. This can also destroy Quality content  on the site.

Comment: And that's what you need to stop doing.  You're not helping yourself by making assumptions. Could that have been their reasoning?  Maybe.  But you have no way of knowing for sure.  So rather than attack actions you have no idea of their motivations, stick to arguing why the question should be re-opened.  If you feel it's a good subjective question, explain why you feel that way.  Stay FAR away from guessing at close voters' reasons.

Comment: @Frank Yes of course I can't be 100% sure. But if someone is smacking a POB closevote because of another reason than "Bad subjective". [It's kind of a misuse of the Closing system](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one). The Downvote and edit button can help in this situation.

Comment: *And you have no idea of their motivations*.  How is it a misuse!?  In order for it to be a misuse, you have to know their motivations!  And *again*, **that's the whole problem**.  Stop assuming you know why people are doing the things they are.  Instead, focus on what you can do to fix it.

Comment: @Frank while i understand what you mean. I must also stress to you that I'm asking the questions I ask because I want answer for them from players or people who are knowlegable in mobas enough to answer them. To a degree I suppose that is why my questions will seem subjective P.O.B etc. However that will not stop me from asking or also asking for help in improving them. I was bronze 2 entering EUW and through the knowledge I gleemed from here as well as other media I am now in silver 1 and confident to reach high ranks.

Comment: @Frank:Basically yes my questions may be downvoted but I think my improvement in the game is testament to the fact that they will help players improve players who want to and seek to improve through knowledge knowledge that can only be gained by asking the right question what I feel should be done is people should point out errors help fix them then leave it be if not then downvote and leave it be I will ask elsewhere there are other media however I prefer this site as the answer are more direct rather than general. Say what you may I asked this question to improve my questions.

Comment: I've read this answer twice, as well as the edit history, and am not sure why there's such a big deal being made in the comments about what assumptions @Jutschge may or may not have made about other people's votes. This answer pretty clearly demonstrates why he believes it should be open, and he doesn't seem to be attacking anyone else. Am I missing something, or is a mountain being made of a molehill here?

Comment: That said, I disagree with the idea that the "main reason" POB questions are bad is because they can't have a single answer. Plenty of perfectly valid questions can have more than one answer.